# May I use flash light during a video call on the phone

Tags: ios, flashlight

Currently I am working on a project (a VoIP app on both Android and iOS) which required flash light during a video call. For iOS, When I making a video call, the flashlight option on the control panel was disabled and turns grey, that is, I am unable to use flashlight.

Any suggestion？

I also checked other VoIP apps such as Skype, same behavious. Is it due to iOS system preventing such action?